# How to convert this query to an expression that can be used in a package?

Tags: ssis

I would like to convert this query to an expression that cab be used in an SSIS package.

```
REPLICATE('0', 12 - LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@SEQ_NUM))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @SEQ_NUM)
```

Expected result:

```
Input: 1234
Output: 000000001234
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need the following expression.

*Expression*:

```
RIGHT(REPLICATE("0",12) + (DT_STR,10,1252)Seq_Num,12)
```

- Use the *REPLICATE* function to generate 12 zeroes
- To the replicated data, append your sequence number input type cast into string. **1252** in the *DT_STR* denotes the code page.
- Use the *RIGHT* function to extract only the 12 characters from the right end of the string.

[image: expression output]